Needing to cut through existing seams in granite countertop
(I put this in the homeimprovement subreddit and it was suggested I post here instead. I don't mean to spam post)
Images here https://imgur.com/a/htShxZo
I am looking to cut the seam supporting a stub piece behind my range so i accomodate a larger range (the older one was 20 years old and shorter -- hence the stub piece behind my range).
Can someone explain the right technique for an amateur to cut this out? Note i have no plans to ever put this back as you cant even get ranges this short anymore.

An oscillating saw, e.g. a Fein Multimaster, with suitable blades, e.g. diamond grit, can make remarkably controlled cuts in all sorts of materials. Eventually. It's not fast and your hands may get numb, but it gets the job done. The seam may be an epoxy that cuts fairly easily with a carbide blade,or even high speed steel.

@HABO I think that would make a good answer.

@HABO could i just use a heat gun and a blade like some other people recommended or would that not work in your experienced opinion?

@LionAndLittleGlass I don't see any other references to a heat gun. I would hope that the seam material is heat resistant since it is part of a kitchen countertop abutting a range. You can try heating something like an old screwdriver and then pressing the tip into a seam to see if there is any effect. I've assumed that the only problematic seams are at the ends of the granite where it meets the rest of the countertop. The granite/wall interface looks like caulk.

Sorry i was referring to other advice i received outside of here. @HABO i appreciate your super detailed reply.

For a one-time job and dealing with the access next to the wall, I'd suggest a simple carbide-grit hacksaw blade.
e.g.  
Image Source, and also: no endorsement implied.
According to your question, you want to cut at the pre-existing epoxy joints. If you wanted to cut the stone itself powered diamond tooling might make more sense, but cutting right up to the wall behind is tricky for most saws or grinders that would otherwise be what I'd reach for first. But that's simple for a hand-powered hacksaw.
You will want to put it into a hacksaw frame rather than using without a frame, as a general rule. Hacksaw blades work best when under tension, though they can be used without a frame where access is limited. Without adequate care that's a good way to bend a blade - putting them under tension in a hacksaw frame greatly reduces that issue.
I have one carbide grit hacksaw blade, which I've used to cut odd shapes in glass (the job I bought it for - it's the "rod" variant, a round blade that cuts any direction - you don't need that for this job), and ceramics, and hardened steel at various points over the years. One of these should be a low cost and fairly quick solution to cut those joints.

Thanks @Ecnerwal this was helpful
